# android database and xml parsing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xml-parsing

I want to know that, is it possible to create the database(including structures and relation between the tables eg. number of columns etc) from the XML feed in android application? If so, then how it can be done? I'm using sax parser.

Comment: first create the tables with column names and the data got from the saxparser can be inserted using insert command from the activity